# wordpress lightbox won't work - worked before?

Tags: jquery, debugging, wordpress, plugins, lightbox

hey guys,
yesterday i finally upgraded my wpmu to wp 3.0.4 . i had the plugin wp-prettyPhoto running successfully before.

Now i can't seem to get it working. the plugin adds a rel="prettyPhoto" attribute to every image on the website and that's the way it triggers the lightbox.

the rel="" attribute still gets addes successfully. However when i click on an image nothing happens. not even the real linked image gets opened. seems like there is something like preventDefault going on.

i have no idea how i could debug this thing: when you click on an image you can see that nothing happens. my theme comes with jquery. the plugin probably as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading the plugin? I don't know about the wp-plugin but you are using the `2.5.6` version of the jquery plugin while the most recent (Stable) version is `3.0`!!

Comment: how can you tell which version i have? my wp version is now 3.0.4 and the plugin version is 1.6.2 which is the latest as well. my theme loads a seperat jquery file which is 1.4.4